# How to apply border for text in css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors, border

Here I have a div with steps as `Step 1`, `Step 2`, `Step 3` in which Step 1 contains active class so it will have the blue border.

**Working Snippet:**

```css
.inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 20%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-flex active">Registration</div>
<div class="inline-flex">User</div>
<div class="inline-flex">Professional Information</div>
```

**Requirement:**

Here the blue border needs to be applied to only the text `Step 1` and **not** to its entire width of 20%.

**Expected Output:**

```
Step 1             Step 2           Step 3
-blue- ---black----black continues--------
```

I have tried applying `position: absolute;` to the `.active` class but it doesn't work as intended.

Kindly please help me to apply `border-bottom: 2px solid blue` only to the text and not the entire width of the div element.

Comment: Wrap the active text in a span, and style that span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give `justify-content: flex-end` to `.inline-flex`, then reset the `width` of the first element to `initial`:

### Edit

If you want the spaces between the texts are equal, use a fixed `padding-left` instead give them `width`:

```css
.inline-flex {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.inline-flex:first-child {
  padding-left: initial;
}

.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <div class="inline-flex active">Registration</div>
  <div class="inline-flex">User</div>
  <div class="inline-flex">Professional Information</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but here if text of the steps is larger then it is not taking equal space.. Please look here https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/poeMpGL

Comment: In real app the text for each step will be like above one only.. So the spacing between each step text needs to be equal..

Comment: @HelloWorld Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

use span

```css
.inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 20%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.active-span {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-flex active"><span class="active-span">Step 1</span> </div>
<div class="inline-flex">Step 2</div>
<div class="inline-flex">Step 3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you wanted, Simply wrap your text in paragraph tag and in style apply border to paragraph instead of whole 20% width inline-flex

```css
.inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 20%;
}

.inline-flex p {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.active p {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-flex active ">
  <p>Registration</p>
</div>
<div class="inline-flex">
  <p>User</p>
</div>
<div class="inline-flex">
  <p>Professional Information</p>
</div>
```